# Strongest way to connect loose 20awg wires together

Tags: connector

Hello I have 4 loose 20 awg wires leaving a stepper motor.  The loose wires are only about 4 inches long and I need at least 5 ft.  Therefore I will be connecting a longer section of wire to the loose wires hanging out of the stepper.  The wires are in a cable drag chain and are thus subject to constant bending which adds stress to the connection between the two sets of wire.

I have considered JST connectors, dupont connectors, spade connectors, soldering the connections...  But not sure the best way to go.

[image: cable tray]

Comment: Define "strongest". Because weldigng them together is strongest. It doesn't appear you are after strongest if you are considering removable connectors. Are you after a permanent connection? Or are you just after a positive locking mechanism?

Comment: Best would be an expensive Kapton flat cable in a large radius controlled U-loop, with ground guard tracks, next best might be fine double twisted pair in a flat braided wire jacket that also traverses with a suitable large U-loop with guides. With tie wraps at the fixed ends.  The wire must move along axis and not radial except at end of large loop. (4~6”D?)

Comment: @DKNguyen it needs to hold-up against constant bending not just tensile strength.

Comment: I'd just use a butt splice and be done with it. Or a Wago connector if you have to undo it.

Comment: If maintenance with a 5 foot cable isn't a pain in the ass I would twist splice like in a blood knot and solder. If maintenance is a pain and it's really going to be flexing as much as you say it is I would only look at positive locking connectors but would still be concerned about fretting corrosion.

Comment: The point where the wires exit the motor may be the weak point. Strain relieving this is important.

Comment: The bending must be at least 40x the wire radius.  We used this criteria to test wires to rotary VCM’s in HDD’s for 1e6 seeks.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 what is meant by this? "bending must be at least 40x wire radius"

Comment: It means the longitudinal motion creates a U-shape bend with fixed ends. The U has a diameter the cable must be guided to stay in this shape or have a flat flexible plastic strap that does it.

Comment: Some of these ideas work well https://www.google.com/search?q=gantry+cable+dressing+stepper&client=firefox-b-m&sxsrf=ALeKk0285NadKSwEEwArMtrLn_qL6V11oQ:1621305633532&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=2qv1jZZ7hKM8_M%252Cdo-Drplu7bOA_M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSzyfzSE-l9_eD7t1XiLizjFFU_aQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC_O6SmtLwAhVOKKwKHXpAAnoQ9QF6BAgREAE#imgrc=2qv1jZZ7hKM8_M but there are even better ways.

Comment: why does the connection have to be inside the cable chain?

Comment: don't put the connection inside the drag chain, only put wire in it there.  fix the connection between the motor wires and the long wires to the same frame as the motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the joins don't need to be massively flexible (i.e. rely on the wire around the joint to flex rather than the joint itself), to be honest a simple solder splice and heatshrink should do the trick.

1. Strip about 10mm of insulation off each wire.
2. Slide at least 30mm of heatshrink tubing over each motor wire.
3. Take the motor wire and your 5ft wire and overlap the stripped ends. If it's stranded wire, trying to intertwine the strands for strength.
4. Solder the two wires together, making sure that the wires are well wetted with solder in the process.
5. slot over the heatshrink and shrink with a hot air gun or hair dryer.

The larger solder area and heatshrink area should provide a pretty solid join. You can increase the length of the heatshrink if you want to 40mm or more to get extra overlap though will limit flexibility.

Comment: Soldering is the easy part. Cable guide is the hard part to minimize radial stress and axial forces.

Comment: This. A solder joint should be perfectly fine for this application.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will support flexible twin twisted pair shielded. But this is tight with layers of plastic tie wrapped to have stiff axial support and flexible radius moving along direction of wire.

If not done right it will add friction and bias torque to the stepper.

[image]
[Ref](https://wiki.shapeoko.com/images/7/71/Wfa_shapeoko_ziptie_cable-mgmnt_mk-iii.JPG)

All soldered connections must be firmly tie wrapped with heat-shrink tubing.

Notice there is an open slotted plastic channel guide for the cable to rest and stay in alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t allow the joints to bend. Provide the splice via direct connection, inline connector or whatever, **then** provide the strain relief and immobilize the wires. Use more strands in the added wire for better life.

Comment: I follow most everything in this post except "... then provide the strain relief and immobilize the wires"  Does this mean immobilize the wires inside the cable tray?  Like zip tying them or something

Comment: yes, clamp, zip tie, or glue them where they enter and exit the chain

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the connection inside the drag chain, only put wire in it there. fix the connection between the motor wires and the long wires to the same frame as the motor.

The junction could be PCB carrying a JST connector with the motor wires strain-releived by weaving through two holes and soldered, screw that to the motor or motor carrying frame. Then run the JST terminated cable through the chain and plug the other end in too.

This gets you most flexibility in the chain and an easily replaced cable if there ever are problems.

Clamping the cable down at each end of the chain will stop it from migrating and causing strain at the terminations.